# Dropped Nikon D7100 with jumpy view finder and clicking sound. Worth having repaired?

Tags: equipment-damage, nikon-d7100

Dropped my camera (long story).  Anyway, the camera shoots fine, except for this clicking sound.  Looking through the view finder the picture jumps a little, but shoots fine.

Worth getting it looked at?  Or no?

Comment: Probably a mirror issue. Is the autofocus working fine on moving subject?

Comment: I would send it to a repair shop ASAP. But did you try to take a picture without a lens mounted on ? For instance a long exposure so you can have a peek. Just do not try to pry stuff :) --- Then I'm not sure you can do this in modern DSLRs.

Answer (score 4):

> Worth getting it looked at?

Yes. There are hundreds of parts in your camera including several low-tolerance ones, there are many things which can go wrong.

Take it to the service now before it breaks and costs you more.

Comment: I'm doubtful that it would cost less to repair (if needed) before it completely breaks compared to after.  They'll probably be doing exactly the same work and replace exactly the same parts.

Comment: @StephenG there are several quickly moving parts in DSLR. If something breaks away it can damage optics, sensor, AF sensor.

Comment: @EuriPinhollow The quickly moving part in this case is likely associated with the VR unit in the lens.

Comment: @MichaelClark the question does not mention the objective. :D

Answer (score 2):

The question isn't exactly clear regarding when the clicking sound is heard or when the view through the viewfinder "jumps around." DOes it happen anytime the shutter button is half pressed and metering is active? Or only when you fully press the shutter button to take the photo?

It sounds like there may be an issue with the VR unit in your lens. Does your lens feature Vibration Reduction? If so turn it off and see if the vibration stops. You can also try a different lens and see if you continue to experience the same problem.

Or you may have a perfectly normally functioning camera. It may have been doing the same things before you dropped it but you didn't notice because you weren't paying as much attention until you were worried you may have damaged the camera after you dropped it. Some noise from a VR unit is normal. Some "jumping around" in the viewfinder is also normal in certain situations, such as panning the camera, when using active VR. To what degree these are normal depends on the specific camera model and lens.